# Angular calendar has not exported member 'DateAdapter' in angular 5

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular-calendar

I have installed this [angular calendar module](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink) in my angular 5 application , by this command .

`npm install --save angular-calendar@0.24.1 date-fns`.

I'm getting this error

[image: error]

**I see there is no docs for angular 5** .

Can anyone help me in this how to use this in **angular 5**.

**Note**: I have installed version `0.24.1` for angular 5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar) is the version you want to use. Since the one you linked is for Angular 6+. Also have you added the `CalendarModule.forRoot({
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useFactory: adapterFactory
    })` part to your module?

Comment: you have given me  the link to angularJs (angular 1). I'm asking about angular 5 @O.MeeKoh

Comment: Did you try adding those lines of code to your imports array in your app.module.ts file for example?

Comment: Yes @O.MeeKoh . If you see the link there is section where it tells about version 0.24.1 for angular 5.

Comment: @Asad any luck about this issue?

Comment: not yet but I will update you when i get something @Asif

Comment: @Asad by the way you can use https://fullcalendar.io library.

Comment: for the time being Im using this `https://github.com/ng-fullcalendar/ng-fullcalendar` @Asif

Comment: Yes I have used the sameJS library but not this module as this is not compatible with Angular4.